# How to make a UIView visible in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have made my view as gone at a certain logic like this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_parentOfPhotoview
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0]];
```

but then again i need to make it visible at a certain point so i tried this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_parentOfPhotoview
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:48]];
```

48 would be the actual height.But its not getting visible. **What i am doing wrong in here??**

Comment: have you called `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` after constraints modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solution is to declare your height constraint as IBOutlet and connect it in IB:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

and change its height this way:

```
- (void)changeHeight:(CGFloat )height {
  self.heightConstraint.constant = height;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
      [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}
```

Comment: doesn't need to be iboutlet. you can create an nslayout property programmatically then initialised it.

Comment: @Joshua yes, that's why I wrote it is one of solution.